# 'Where' and 'IN' in ruby on rails to avoid SQL injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am changing an existing query to avoid SQL injection.The query goes like this

```
People.select('DISTINCT people_id')
      .where(person_id: id)
      .where("position_id IN (#{approval_id.join(', ')})")
      .where('ended_on IS NULL or ended_on > ?', Date.today)
```

where approval_id is array with value [1, 2, 3, 4]

when I am changing the query line 3

```
.where("position_id IN (#{approval_id.join(', ')})") to
.where("position_id IN ?", approval_id)
```

It is not working. what is going wrong? as approval_id is an array I can pass it directly to an IN.

Comment: Put `()` around the query param, so `(?)`. IIRC you can also just write `where(position_id: approval_id)`. Unrelated, but I would name the variable to reflect it's a collection, `approval_ids`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pass in an array and Rails will convert it to an `in` query](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions).

```
People
  .select('DISTINCT people_id')
  .where(
    person_id: id,
    position_id: approval_id, # approval_ids?
  )
  .where("ended_on is null or ended_on > ?", Date.today)
```

`nil` will be converted to `is null` and you can use [`and`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#and-conditionsd) and [`or`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) to keep this entirely within ActiveRecord.

```
People
  .select('DISTINCT people_id')
  .where(
    person_id: id,
    position_id: approval_id, # approval_ids?
  )
  .and(
    People
      .where(ended_on: nil)
      .or(People.where(ended_on > ?", Date.today)
  )
```

Though this is arguably more complicated in this query, it's useful to know for others.

Comment: It is bizarre that the Rails Guides do not mention this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

Comment: @DavidAldridge They do under the obscure name "subset conditions"; I linked to it. "Array conditions" refers to passing multiple, distinct bind values as an Array. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Arel instead of strings:

```
people_table = People.arel_table

People
 .select(:people_id)
 .where(person_id: id)
 .where(people_table[:position_id].in(approval_id))
 .where(
   people_table[:ended_on].eq(nil).or(
     people_table[:ended_on].gt(Date.today)
   )
 ).distinct
```